# Univariate vs multivariate analysis (p-value)

Tags: multivariate-analysis, univariate

So I have been looking through some literature/articles, and something I often come across is, that when they do some kind of analysis it's often univariate and multivariate analysis on for example biochemical failure after 5 years.
Typically they look at some number of variables (let's say 10), then they run the analysis and a p-value is presented, and sometimes also a hazard ratio.

I am just trying to figure out how this is done exactly ? Or maybe it's very different, or not very common ? Like, I understand univariate. You test one independent variable against your dependent variable, and see if they are correlated in some way. But how would a multivariate analysis work ? Do one just test all variables at the same time in a linear regression or logistic regression, and that's that ? Or what is the typical approach ? Some form of step-wise selection maybe ?

Comment: Multivariate analysis is a broad term that captures the essence of analysing multiple variables in one unified workflow. There's many ways of doing this (not one exact way) , depending on how independent the variables are. Variables that share little information can be used in a straightforward regression, otherwise variable selection or /and data reduction are just two of the strategies that can be employed. As a general principle multivariate methods actively incorporate information about how the variables interact. Could you be a bit more concrete in terms of what you want?

Comment: This sounds like a very broad question